# Trigger heavy task on view model's property change

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm creating a video/frame editor and I wonder what would be the best approach for triggering a render cycle whenever the user scrubs (manually navigate to specific time) or playback is triggered.

Render is done using a `WriteableBitmap` back buffer, so I always need to mark the frame as dirty (in the UI thread) when the render cycle is complete.

Initially I thought about triggering render on a `TimeSpan` property changed, but that's doesn't look right as it may be too heavy of a task and it would hang the UI.

```
public TimeSpan CurrentTime 
{
   get => _currentTime;
   set 
   {
      _currentTime = value;
    
      //Render frame animation based on current time.
      Render();
   }
}
```

My goals are:

1. Don't freeze the UI.
2. Drop frames if the rendering takes too much to complete or the current time is switched too fast.
3. Less delay possible to render when switching current time.

What's the most used (or better) approach in this case?
Maybe trigger a command?

Comment: What about a Background worker thread which triggers rerendering on a AutoResetEvent?

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to research about it. Thanks.